# how to detect a callout of an annotation is showing on mapview?

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

I have a checkin related app. When user clicks a venue on map, callout will popup and show its name and address. At the same time, if the venue is within 1000m from current location, a check in button will be displayed.

To a venue that can checkin, all I want is,

when callout is popup, check in button shows. when callout is disappear, that button disappears too.

Now show button works well, but I don't know how to detect callout visible status. Is there any callback method that callout show/hide?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Callout appears when annotation is selected - you can use `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` method in delegate to track that event. Callout hides when annotation is deselected - use `mapView:didDeselectAnnotationView:` method to track that event.

Comment: Thanks. but when I tap the mapview, callout hides but the annotation is still selected.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/selected) it is about **selected** property of MKAnnotationView, which is saying that **If the property contains YES, the annotation view is displaying a callout bubble.**

You may additionally implement an observer for this property, to implement your functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much. use selected property is a simple and clear way.