# How to determine whether a MKPinAnnotationView CallOut is shown or not?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, mapkit

I know how to make an MKPinAnnotation show and hide the annotation CallOut window.

But is there a property which I could query that would return a boolean as to whether the annotation CallOut window is currently visible or not?

Comment: Try the annotation view's `selected` property.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419729/how-to-detect-a-callout-of-an-annotation-is-showing-on-mapview.

Comment: Hi @Anna, that works perfectly.  I must had been blind to not see it.  If you want to just put the above as an answer I will accept.  Thank you.